# If $a+b+c+d=1$ then why is the maximum value of $(a+1)(b+1)(c+1)(d+1)$ is ${\left(\frac{5}{4}\right)}^4$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic, problem-solving

What I know is that for equations of type $x+y=8$, $xy$ attains its maximum value when $x=y$ and this can be proved by either solving the quadratic equation with [completing the squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completing_the_square) or finding the first and second derivatives of $xy$ w.r.t. $x$ to perform maxima/minima test. But both of these methods are applicable only when there is not more than one independent variable -- here $x$ is independent variable and $y=8-x$ is the dependent one.

I don't understand why $(a+1)(b+1)(c+1)(d+1)$ attains its maximum value at $a=b=c=d$ within the condition of $a+b+c+d=1$. How can we prove this fact? In some other similar posts I saw others using the [Lagrange multiplier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier) method. This method is too advanced for me to understand. I'm looking for some kind of algebraic proof similar to comleting with sqaure proof as in case of finding the maximum value of $xy$.

Comment: Each answer below utilizes [arithmetic-geometric mean inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means).  I've linked to it in case you haven't seen it before.  In general the arithmetic mean equals the geometric mean when all are equal (as is the case with your 2 variable scenario with $x$ and $y$).

Comment: Note that we need conditions on $a,b,c,d$. For example by choosing $a=b=-1000$ and $c$ and $d$ appropriately, we can make the product quite large.

Comment: Indeed. The AM-GM inequality requires that each of the terms being compared by the inequality be non-negative, which in this case means $a,b,c,d\geq -1$

Comment: Yes, I think $a,b,c$ and $d$ must be positive but unfortunately the question statement in the book doesn't impose any condition. It doesn't even say whether $a,b,c$ and $d$ can be complex numbers or not. And more unfortunately the question was asked in an exam.

Comment: If no conditions were given @user103816, then a disproof by counterexample would be appropriate, such as taking as Andre suggests $a=b=-1000$ and $c=d=1000.5$, you'll have $(a+1)(b+1)(c+1)(d+1)\approx 1000^4\gg (\frac{5}{4})^4$, disproving the claim.

Comment: @AndréNicolas In my example of $x+y=8$, $xy$ has still the maximum value of $16$ for both positive and negative choices of $x$ and $y$. Why does the AM-GM inequality works here?

Comment: But it will not work for more variables. In the case of two variables with sum $8$, obviously we cannot make both negative. But if the number of variables is $\gt 2$, we can make two of them large negative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the maximum of $(5/4)^4$ is only if the variables are required to be bigger than $-1$. E.g. $(-10)+(-10)+10+11 = 1$ and $(-9)(-9)(11)(12) > (5/4)^4$.

Assuming the $\geq -1$ condition, using different variables ($u=a+1,v=b+1,w=c+1,x=d+1$) the problem can also be written as: given $u,v,w,x \geq 0$, $u+v+w+x =5$, what is the maximum value of $uvwx$?

The symmetry of the problem suggests that the max should occur when $u=v=w=x$, so the condition $u+v+w+x = 5$ implies they should all be equal to $5/4$. Now how do we show that this is actually the max?

Obviously the max does not occur when any of them are equal to zero, so let's exclude those cases. Suppose that two of them were not equal, i.e. $u \neq v$. Let's show that in this case we can strictly increase the product by replacing $u$ and $v$ with their average, $\frac{u+v}{2}$.

$$
\frac{u+v}{2}\frac{u+v}{2}wx > uvwx
$$
$$
\iff u^2+v^2 + 2uv > 4uv
$$
$$
\iff  u^2 + v^2 -2uv > 0
$$
$$
\iff (u-v)^2 > 0
$$
$$
\iff \text{True}
$$
Note that $(u-v)^2$ will be strictly bigger than zero because $u\neq v$. Thus we can strictly do better by replacing $u,v$ with their average. Thus, in order for $uvwx$ to be maximized, every pair of the variables must be equal. But then they are all equal, i.e. $u=v=w=x=\frac{5}{4}$ and you have your result.

Comment: There is a problem in your proof. What you have shown is $uvwx$ increases if $w$ and $x$ remain fixed and $u$ and $v$ both are replaced with $(u+v)/2$. But actually when you will change $u$ and $v$ both to $(u+v)/2 $, $w$ and $x$ both will decrease making the product decrease. Let initial values be $u_1,v_1,w_1$ and $x_1$ Let $u$ and $v$ are changed to $A$ both, now $w$ and $x$ will be changed to $w_2$ and $x_2$. What we have to prove is $u_1v_1w_1x_1 \leq AAw_2x_2$.

Comment: "Symmetry suggests that..." But of course you need more computation, as you have given.  Note that also "symmetry suggests that" the *minimum* occurs when $u=v=w=x$.

Comment: @user103816, the variables go from $(u,v,w,x)$ to $(\frac{u+v}{2},\frac{u+v}{2},w,x)$. The variables $w$ and $x$ stay exactly the same, they do not decrease. You can check that $5=u+v+w+x = \frac{u+v}{2}+\frac{u+v}{2}+w+x$ so there is no need to change $w,x$. I'm not claiming that this new set of vars is the maximum, I'm just showing that unless $u=v=w=x$, then the vars you chose are *not* a maximum.

Comment: @GEdgar, my symmetry comment is meant to show the reader where I got the proof idea from. It is intuition, not a proof. Thankfully I followed it up with an actual proof. Notice that if my intuition had said "minimum" instead of "maximum" the $>$ would have to be a $<$ in the string of iffs, and I would not have been able to complete the proof.

Comment: I didn't get this step: "_Thus, in order for $uvwx$ to be maximized, every pair of the variables must be equal_". I understood that for any given $w$ and $x$, $uvwx$ will be maximum when $u=v$. But how can we show that if every pair is equal then the product is maximized?

Comment: @user103816. By compactness, the maximum must exist. Now suppose that the max occurs with $(u,v,w,x)$. If $u\neq v$, then my proof shows that I could do strictly better, which would contradict that $uvwx$ is a maximum. Thus $u=v$. Similarly, if $v \neq w$, the proof would show $uvwx$ is not a max, so it must be that $v=w$. Finally, if $w \neq x$, again $uvwx$ wouldn't be a max, so it must be that $w=x$. Thus $u=v=w=x$.

Comment: Your proof is that from $u,v,w$ and $x$ if any pair is equal then the product will be greater than any other combination in which no pair is equal. At a time we can either show that $u_0=w_0$ does strictly better for $u_0v_0wx$ than any other combination $u_1v_1wx(u_1 \neq v_1)$ **or** similarly $v_2=w_2$ does strictly better for $uv_2w_2x$ than any other combination $uv_4w_4x$($v_4 \neq w_4$). We haven't shown that $u_3=v_3=w_3$ does strictly better for $u_3v_3w_3x$ than any other combination $u_6v_6w_6x$ where $(u_6 \neq v_6 \neq w_6)$ .

Comment: @user103816 That is **not** what my proof says. My proof shows that for $(u,v,w,x)$ if some two of them are not equal, then $uvwx$ is not maximized under the given constraint. The statement "$uvwx$ is maximized" implies that the hypothesis of my implication is false, i.e. "not (some two of $(u,v,w,x)$ are not equal))" holds. Expanding this we see it is equivalent to "every two of $(u,v,w,x)$ are equal", i.e. $u=v=w=x$.

Comment: I still don't get it. I agree if some two of the intezers aren't equal then we can make the product larger by making those two equal and leaving the others same. Let we make $u=v$ from this point how do we show that making $u=v=w$ will further increase the product? And choosing $u=v=w=x$ will again further increase the product? My idea is that we can first show the fact for $u=v$ and then for $w=x$, then let $uv=p$ and $wx=q$, now $pq$ will be maximized for $p=q$ wich shows $u=v=w=x$ is a maxima. But this argument doesn't work for odd numbers of intezers, e.g. for $a+b+c=const$ and $abc$[cont]

Comment: is the required product. But if I could understand your method then I can make a general method for $n$ variables $a_1,a_2,...,a_n$ s.t. $a_1+a_2+...a_n=\text{constant}$ and $a_1a_2...a_n$ is maximized at $a_1=a_2=...=a_n$

Comment: @user103816, you are thinking about it too hard. I did **not** show that first setting $u=v$, then setting $v=w$, then setting $w=x$ will somehow increase the product three times and be maximal. Instead, **start with** the maximum $(u,v,w,x)$. Is it possible that $u\neq v$? No, then I could increase the product. Is it possible that $v \neq w$? No, then I could increase the product. Is it possible that $w \neq x$? No, then I could increase the product. Thus they must all be equal.

Comment: Perhaps I understand it now as: Let $x_1,x_2,x_3\cdots x_n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i=constant.$ Now the product $\prod_{i=1}^{n} x_i$ can be divded in two cases. **Case I:** At least one pair $x_j\neq x_k$ where $j \neq k$. **Case II:** $x_j=x_k$ for every $j,k$ such that $0<j,k \leq n$ and $j\neq k$. Now case I is not a maximum. This leaves us with case II being the unique maxima because there has to be at least one maxima.

Comment: @user103816, now you've got it. The only stipulation is that we need to assume that $x_i \geq 0$ for all $i$ so as to ensure the allowed values of $x_i$ form a compact set in $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 5):

You known AM-GM inequality?
$$(a+1)(b+1)(c+1)(d+1)\le\left(\dfrac{a+b+c+d+4}{4}\right)^4$$

if you don't known AM-GM inequality,you also can following

In fact ,if $x,y,z,w\in R^{+}$,then we have
$$x^4+y^4+z^4+w^4-4xyzw\ge 0$$
because
$$x^4+y^4+z^4+w^4-4xyzw=(x^2-y^2)^2+(z^2-w^2)+2(xy-zw)^2$$
so $=$ iff $x=y=z=w$
so
$$4xyzw\le \le x^4+y^4+z^4+w^4$$
let
$$\sqrt[4]{a+1}=x,\sqrt[4]{b+1}=y,\sqrt[4]{c+1}=z,\sqrt[4]{d+1}=w$$
so
$$4\sqrt[4]{(a+1)(b+1)(c+1)(d+1)}\le a+1+b+1+c+1+d+1=5$$

so
$$(a+1)(b+1)(c+1)(d+1)\le \left(\dfrac{5}{4}\right)^4$$

Comment: No, I didn't know about AM-GM inequality.

Comment: @JMoravitz,oh,Thank you

Answer (score 5):

By the AM-GM inequality,

$$\sqrt[4]{(a+1)(b+1)(c+1)(d+1)} \leq \frac{(a + 1) + (b + 1) + (c + 1) + (d + 1)}{4} = \frac{5}{4}$$

hence...

Comment: But how can we conclude that $a=b=c=d$ is the only possible solution for it?

Comment: @user103816 The max is $\le \frac{5}{4}$, and when $a = \dots = d$ the value is $\frac{5}{4}$, so it must be the max.

Comment: From the general result of the AM-GM inequality, $(a_1a_2\cdots a_n)^{1/n} = \frac{a_1 + a_2 + \cdots + a_n}{n}$ iff $a_1 = a_2 = \cdots = a_n$. Thus in this case, $a +1 = b + 1 = c + 1 = d + 1$, i.e., $a = b = c = d$.

Comment: But there may be other valuse of $a,b...$ for which $(a+1)(b+1)(c+1)(d+1)=\dfrac 54$ How to prove that $ a=b=c=d$ is the **only** possible solution?

Comment: From the "if and only if" of the result I just quoted.

Comment: Ok, it is the theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Using AM, GM inequity

$$\dfrac{\sum (a+1)}4\ge\sqrt[4]{\prod(a+1)}$$

Answer (score 1):

In light of all the AM-GM answers, here is a variational approach.

Suppose we know that $a+b+c+d=1$, then we also know that for any direction moved $(\delta a,\delta b,\delta c,\delta d)$ that maintains this condition
$$
\begin{align}
0
&=\delta a+\delta b+\delta c+\delta d\\
&=(\delta a,\delta b,\delta c,\delta d)\cdot(1,1,1,1)\tag{1}
\end{align}
$$
In that same direction, the rate of change of $(a+1)(b+1)(c+1)(d+1)$ satisfies
$$
\begin{align}
\small\frac{\delta\left[(a+1)(b+1)(c+1)(d+1)\right]}{(a+1)(b+1)(c+1)(d+1)}
&=\small\frac{\delta a}{a+1}+\frac{\delta b}{b+1}+\frac{\delta c}{c+1}+\frac{\delta d}{d+1}\\
&\small=(\delta a,\delta b,\delta c,\delta d)\cdot\left(\frac1{a+1},\frac1{b+1},\frac1{c+1},\frac1{d+1}\right)\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
**Case 1: $\boldsymbol{a,b,c,d\gt0}$ (interior maximum)**

Suppose we are at the point where $(a+1)(b+1)(c+1)(d+1)$ is maximum given that $a+b+c+d=1$. Suppose further that we can find a direction that is perpendicular to $(1,1,1,1)$, but is not perpendicular to $\left(\frac1{a+1},\frac1{b+1},\frac1{c+1},\frac1{d+1}\right)$. Then, since $a,b,c,d\gt0$, by $(1)$, we can travel in that direction, and its opposite, and $a+b+c+d$ will stay constant. However, by $(2)$, moving in that direction, or its opposite, will cause $(a+1)(b+1)(c+1)(d+1)$ to increase.  This contradicts the maximality we assumed.

Thus, if $a,b,c,d\gt0$, $\left(\frac1{a+1},\frac1{b+1},\frac1{c+1},\frac1{d+1}\right)$ must be parallel to $(1,1,1,1)$. That is, $a=b=c=d=\frac14$.

**Case 2: one or more of $\boldsymbol{a,b,c,d=0}$ (boundary maximum)**

Using the same arguments as above, we get that the non-zero variables must be equal. So we must not only check $\left(\frac14,\frac14,\frac14,\frac14\right)$, but also $\left(0,\frac13,\frac13,\frac13\right)$, $\left(0,0,\frac12,\frac12\right)$, and $(0,0,0,1)$.

Since
$$
\left(\frac54\right)^4\ge\left(\frac43\right)^3\ge\left(\frac32\right)^2\ge2^1
$$
we get that the maximum occurs at $\left(\frac14,\frac14,\frac14,\frac14\right)$.

Comment: I don't get how equation 2 is deduced. Do you use $\delta$ to represent change?

Comment: $\delta x$ represents an instantaneous change in $x$. You can think of it as $\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t}$ given the appropriate path parametrized by $t$. Equation $(2)$ is simply the chain rule.